# IndentationError in Django

Tags: python, django

I am a Django newbie writing my first app.
When testing it I got this error:

```
IndentationError at /polls
expected an indented block (views.py, line 28)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://139.162.221.107:8000/polls
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: IndentationError
Exception Value:    
expected an indented block (views.py, line 28)
Exception Location: /home/devuser/Django-apps/poolApp/polls/urls.py in <module>, line 3
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

So my guess Its that the error is on the file urls.py, but I don't see any thing wrong

File: urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

Comment: the traceback mentions the file `views.py`. that's where i suppose the error is.

Comment: What's on line 28 of `views.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My students used to get this error all the time. It most likely means 1 of 2 things.

First, line 28 of your views.py file is indenting when it shouldn't. You might want to check the previous line as well.

or

You are mixing tabs and spaces (this one was the more common problem).

If this doesn't solve it, please post the views.py file.

Comment: triple-quoted string literal !